# Why does my Visual Studio 2005 detach from the process when I start the debugger?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, debugging

I'm using VS2005 to develop a web application. When I start debugging it will open the web page but the immediately detach from the process. I have found that if I close the IDE and start it back up it will work fine for a while but then start detaching again. Any insight into this odd behaviour would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Err... Do you have another debugger? I believe that if another debugger attach itself to the process it would remove the Visual Studio debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using IE8? I ran into a similar issue recently, after installing IE8. It turns out IE8 uses multiple processes and Visual Studio doesn't know which process to attach to. The registry fix in [this](http://dpotter.net/Technical/2009/05/upgrading-to-ie8-breaks-debugging-with-visual-studio-2005/) article remedied the issue for me.

Comment: This was exactly it. One more reason to push for an upgrade to 2008!