# Why won't my VS 2005 hit the break points?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2005, web-config, projects-and-solutions

I'm going crazy and wasting a lot of time. I am running in DEBUG, checked the web.config to ensure debug=true is there, checked the code to ensure I am reaching it, cleared all temp files and pdb's. The only thing that works is to continually kill the solution, create a new solution and add all the projects again. I shouldn't have to do this every day.

Comment: If you have never got it working, why should you do it everyday? Did I miss something?

Comment: Is this running in IE8? I had a similar problem in VS2005, found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799234/why-does-my-visual-studio-2005-detach-from-the-process-when-i-start-the-debugger/1800258  I didn't have this problem after we upgraded to VS2008

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows Vista, try launching Visual Studio as an Administrator.  Even if you're already running as an Administrator on the machine, still right-click on Visual Studio and select "Run as Administrator."

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the solution node in solution explorer end select Properties. Check the configuration settings in there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your visual Studio is not attaching your project with process WebDev.WebServer.EXE

Do the following Steps:

1. click on Debug Menu
2. Click on Attach to process WebDev.WebServer.EXE

Now your Debugging is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attaching to a process sometimes this can be caused by symbols not being loaded. If you see the code skip over your breakpoint hover over the breakpoint it will tell you if symbols were not loaded. If that is the case Here are several potential solutions to your problem.

1. Clear out all files in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ASP.Net temp files.
2. Ensure you deployed the *.pdb files to the bin folder of your application.
3. The web process has not loaded your assemblies at the time you attach your debugger. Reset the process and wait a little longer before attaching to the process to give the process a chance to load your dll's.