# Visual studio 2005 debugger won't stop at requested break points

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2005

I have `debug=true` both in the `web.config` and in the requested file but it still won't stop.

Thanks...

Comment: Also please check for next question, it could be the case:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799234/why-does-my-visual-studio-2005-detach-from-the-process-when-i-start-the-debugger/1800258

Answer (score 0):

There might be several reasons:

1. There are changes to the assembly and the debugger didn't get updated - try cleaning the solution and the building it again
2. You are building in release mode - in this case you would get a warning message from the studio

The rest options depends on weather you are using local iis or the Visual Studio web server.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
The weird thing is that it worked and then suddenly stopped.

1. What do you mean by cleaning the solution? how do i do that?

I think I'm working with the vs web server (the default option).

Comment: You can clean the solution or the project by right clicking in the solution explorer on the solution/project and then select "Clean Solution" from the menu. Other option is from the top menu "Build" -> "Clean Solution" or "Build" -> "Clean Your_Project_Name"